# Socket Exception when Connecting from Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, client-server

I try to do an example about client-server Windows Phone app
but when I debug code, there is a error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException'
>   occurred in System.dll
>
> Additional information: No connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely
>   continued.

What should I do?

Comment: Sounds like the target machine (your server) likely is blocking the connection either with a firewall, or the fact that the server application isn't running.

Comment: Can you post sample code?

Comment: thanks, is is an example from http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/TCP-IP-Server-Client-0964d476
i didn't change anything
my server writed by Java still works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the port , the firewall may be blocking some of the ports associated with another applications.

For internal use you can use IP 127.0.0.1 , Port 5738

Best Regards,
Yaniv Jacob Jacob